# Passing in a prop and setting it as data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to pass a prop from my drop down button component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p @click="toggleActive">Open Drop Down</p>
        <drop-down :active="this.active"></drop-down>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                active: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleActive() {
                return this.active = ! this.active;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

To my drop down component:

```
<template>
    <div class="drop-down" v-if="this.passedActive">
        <p @click="toggleActive">Close drop down</p>
            ....

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['active'],
        data() {
            return {
                passedActive: this.active,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleActive() {
           
                return this.passedActive = ! this.passedActive;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The idea is that I can activate the drop down component from it's parent, and then inside the drop down component I can modify this prop and deactivate the drop down - as if someone is pressing an 'x' inside the component.

I've checked the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props) and this does appear to be the correct way to do it, but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: `:active="active"` not `:active="this.active"`

Comment: thanksd - thanks but it still doesn't pass the prop correctly to the child's data, although the prop is definitely being passed according to vue tools.

Comment: That's only part of the issue. The other part is that when the prop changes, the component doesn't know because data is only initialized once. You need to use a computed or watch.

Comment: Bert - thanks but the child component does know when the parents prop is changed, I had it working before hitting this bug.

Comment: The data function is only called when the component is created. That means that `passedActive` will only be set on initialization or when the `toggleActive` method is called. It will not change when `active` changes. If you used `active` in the template, then it would update when active changes.

Comment: Bert - it should be set when created, but it is not, I don't care about reactivity for now, why, when created is the data not being set from the prop?

Comment: That's answered in the first comment. You have to bind the property.

Comment: Bert - I have done that on the parent component - is that not in the right place?

Comment: Should be working if you have it bound now. If it's not, then there doesn't appear to be anything in the posted code that would cause it not to.

Comment: Is there a reason you are separating the button from the dropdown in different components? You could combine these components into one, making the states you are looking for a lot easier to achieve

Comment: I know I am following the docs and have it laid out the same - cannot figure this out.

Comment: Taylor Foster - separate components as there are a variety of drop downs throughout the site using the same drop down component but not the same initiating button

Comment: Did you also change `v-if="this.passedActive"` to `v-if="passedActive"`?

Comment: Yes I also changed that.

Comment: Maybe still combine them and then just add a prop something like `['toggle']` in which you could just check against that value and output a button, anchor tag, whatever. Just use conditional rendering. `<drop-down toggle="button"></drop-down>` or `<drop-down toggle="anchor"></drop-down>`

Comment: Then what isn't working as expected? The `active` property in the parent is initially set to `false`. That's what gets passed as the drop down component's `active` prop. So the `passedActive` prop is set to `false` and the component won't display. Nothing is going to update the value `passedActive`, so it will always be `false`, unless you use a computed property or watcher like Bert mentioned.

Comment: thanksd - that is correct, I'm getting confused because active is false, so the child component should not be created.

Comment: If you had a `v-if` on the component's tag that would be true. But you have a `v-if` on the root element in the component's template. The component is created and then the template is rendered and the `v-if` is resolved based on the `passedActive` prop.

Comment: thanksd - ive just added the v-if to the <template> tag, now it is rendered straight away, even though the passedActive var is false

Comment: That won't work, you'd need to add `v-if` to the `<drop-down>` tag in the parent's template.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/j4lwk21j39

Comment: <drop-down v-if="passedActive"></drop-down> still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks Bert but you've used a computed property - I want to follow the data example as per the official docs

Comment: What example would that be?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props - under one way data flow

Comment: @panthro `passedActive` isn't a property in the parent's scope, it'd need to be `v-if="active"`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/2390w1p8w0

Comment: thanksd- yes that's correct, so when you click to open, it opens, passes in active to passedActive correctly. But it doesn't work as I would like because I would like the v-if to now be bassed on passedActive but its bound to active on the <template> tag. Is there anyway to actually do this?

Comment: Bert - thanks for providing an emit answer, not entirely what I am looking for but helpful indeed.

Comment: @panthro you can't conditionally render a component in a parent scope based on a property of that child component because when the child component is not rendered its data won't exist. You need to use a value in the parent's scope when deciding whether or not to conditionally render the child via `v-if`

Comment: thanksd - thanks for the info, you have greatly improved my vue knowledge today, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works. As noted in the comments under your question, `passedActive` is initialized once. The parent controls the initial state (only), and the child itself controls any subsequent state. If you start with it false, it never gets to become true, because the controller is never displayed.

That is a design flaw: there should be one data item that controls it, not two. The child component should rely on its prop, and its toggle function should emit an event that the parent handles.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive() {
      console.log("Toggling");
      this.active = !this.active;
    }
  },
  components: {
    dropDown: {
      props: ['active'],
      data() {
        return {
          passedActive: this.active,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        toggleActive() {
          return this.passedActive = !this.passedActive;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="toggleActive">Open Drop Down {{active}}</p>
  <drop-down :active="active" inline-template>
    <div class="drop-down" v-if="this.passedActive">
      <p @click="toggleActive">Close drop down</p>
    </div>
  </drop-down>
</div>
```